# Round number to the closest multiple of 0.11 via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, rounding

I need to round a number to the closest multiple of 0.11 or to a round whole number

Example:

```
0.99 turns to 1.00
0.87 turns to 0.88
0.59 turns to 0.55
54.01 turns to 54.00
```

Comment: why? the error is smaller with return of 0.99 and 54.01

Comment: using it for a site using a video game's currencies, which go from 0.11 -> 0.22 -> 0.33 -> (like that) -> 1.00 -> 1.11 -> (and it goes on).

Comment: So round to nearest whole only if it ends with `.99` ?

Comment: Indeed, and round down when it's .01

Comment: but 0.99 is also a multiple of 0.11, i.e. 0.11 * 9... which means that your example is somewhat incorrect

Comment: The question was already answered, but I'll explain anyway, the main currency's has a sub-currency (like pennies) that needs 9 of it to make a whole (like dollars), so 8 is 0.88 and 9 would supposedly be 0.99 but it's whole then.

Comment: With two exceptions, none of your sample values can even be represented using a finite floating point representation.Unless you provide a more concise problem statement, you will have to be prepared for "funny" effects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to separate the integer part and the fractional part. If the fractional part is close to factor 9, then return the integer part plus one, otherwise the integer part plus the corrected fractional part.

```js
function getRight(v) {
    var i = Math.floor(v),
        f = Math.round((v - i) / 0.11);                
    return i + (f === 9 || f * 0.11);
}

var array = [0.99, 0.87, 0.59, 54.01],
    result = array.map(getRight);

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: I couldn't get this solution to work with negative numbers. Changing the integer part to `var i = v > 0 ? Math.floor(v) : Math.ceil(v)` worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you mean this:

```
function roundStop(n) {return n%10==0?n/10:(n-n%10)/10+(n%10)*0.11}
function round(x){
var i=0;
while(roundStop(i)-x<0)i++;
return roundStop(i-1)-x>x-roundStop(i)?roundStop(i-1):roundStop(i)
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Math.floor Rounds down
Math.ceil Rounds Up

Comment: that's not what i was talking about, that only solves a part of the question.

Comment: Then maybe you should rephrase your question to AND instead of OR.

Comment: I've phrased my question correctly, in some cases it should round to the cloest multiple of 0.11 and in some other cases it should round to the closest whole number.